# Getting “Connection Refused” when trying to connect to Apache Kafka running on port 9092 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have a problem to open a specific port on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

I can connect from my server to the Raspberry Pi (and vice versa) using the shell and port 22 as well as with VNC.

`nmap -sS localhost` on the Raspberry Pi returns:

```
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

There are no rules in IPTables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However for a port used to send data from a Apache Kafka Producer API instance the following fails:

```
telnet 192.168.2.113 9092
Trying 192.168.2.113...Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)     
telnet: connect to address 192.168.2.113: Connection refused
```

I have tried to add the allowed ports to iptables and also did a

```
sudo ufw allow 9092
```

But the problem remains. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you update your question to add details as to which version of Apache Kafka you’re using?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with Apache Kafka, the big clue to your problem to me comes from the fact your NMap output doesn’t show anything for port `9092` despite the firewall rules being—essentially—dead and allowing all traffic. In a case like that if your service port is not shown via Nmap it means that the application is not really networking outside of the device or the networking config is not set to network off of the device.

As explained in the [Apache Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whycan%27tmyconsumers/producersconnecttothebrokers?) under the title “Why can't my consumers/producers connect to the brokers?”:

> When a broker starts up, it registers its ip/port in ZK. You need to make sure the registered ip is consistent with what's listed in `metadata.broker.list` in the producer config. By default, the registered ip is given by `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress`. Typically, this should return the real ip of the host. However, sometimes (e.g., in EC2), the returned ip is an internal one and can't be connected to from outside. The solution is to explicitly set the host ip to be registered in ZK by setting the "`hostname`" property in `server.properties`. In another rare case where the binding host/port is different from the host/port for client connection, you can set `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port` for client connection.

So basically Apache Producer config needs to be adjusted—in your case—to factor in the `192.168.2.113` as the publicly available IP address.

So based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879712/117259), I would recommend doing the following… Stop your instance of Apache Kafka, open up the `config/server.properties` file and adjust or add these lines:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.2.113:9092
```

And this:

```
bootstrap.servers=192.168.2.113:9092
```

Save the file, start the application and do another `nmap 192.168.2.113` and port `9092` should show up in that list as open.

Or…

You can set the IP address value to `0.0.0.0` which (in the networking world) equates to “Bind this application to any/all interfaces on the device.”

So your config settings would look like this:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

And this:

```
bootstrap.servers=0.0.0.0:9092
```

Save the config and start the application again and now you can reach port `9092` regardless of what the IP address is. This is useful in situations where the IP address is prone to change such as in environments where you are using DHCP address assignment instead of a static IP address.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Before I created the question I read about advertised.listeners and bootstrap.servers and tried some combinations already with the IP address. However I always get a kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs from the raspberry

Comment: one more comment. The meta address for me is not working, the service is not starting up with exeception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.

Comment: Very odd all around. Can you [look at this Git issue thread](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/607#issuecomment-422498959) and see if anything helps? At the end of the day I am quite positive this is an Apache Kafka binding/networking issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting it running, so I solved it differently using MQTT (mosquitto) on my raspberry pi, nifi for the connection and the push to Kafka.

Answer (score -1):

Well...it could be a number of things, but going off of the "Connection Refused" error I would say it is likely a permissions issue. You could always check the auth.log file in:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

To possibly see where the disagreement is. Now if you are trying to access the port for user, say, **root** you will not have permission to access (and rightly so). Also since your **ufw allow** of 9092, I would do another **nmap** and double check that the port is actually open. It would do good to **nmap** the pi from your remote server as well.

I would check syslog and auth.log when trying to connect to try and get a clearer picture of what is going on.

Comment: Why would the `auth.log` and `syslog` have anything to do with a networking issues?